# Ping диапазона адресов

Tags: python

Есть код который пингует все адреса в подсети, но мне нужно пинговать начиная с 100 адреса, есть идеи как это сделать? Если вместо 192.168.21.0/24 ввести 192.168.21.100/24, то выдает ошибку,

```
import subprocess
import ipaddress

net_addr = '192.168.21.0/24'
ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)

all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())

info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE


for i in range(len(all_hosts)):
    output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '50', str(all_hosts[i])], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      startupinfo=info).communicate()[0]

    if "Destination host unreachable" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Offline")
    elif "Request timed out" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Offline")
    else:
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Online")
```

Comment: Разумеется, выдаст ошибку. потому что маска у вас - 24. Читайте в интернете про network mask и подбирайте правильный адрес и маску.

Comment: Адрес то верный и маска тоже, просто мне нужно чтобы пинг начинался не с 192.168.21.1, а с 192.168.21.100, так как пока код просканирует все 255 адресов пройдет очень много времени,

Comment: прочитайте, все-таки, про network masks - много интересного для себя откроете. У вас адрес и маска верны, но не для вашей задачи.

Answer (score 2):

all_hosts содержит список хостов сгенерированых из маски. просто возьми срез.

```
import ipaddress
net_addr = '192.168.21.0/24'
ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)
all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())
print(all_hosts[0])  # 192.168.21.1
print(all_hosts[99:][0])  # 192.168.21.100
```

Comment: Кстати, да, так проще )

Comment: Спасибо, но я не понял, тут идет с 1 и до 100 адреса, а мне нужно начиная с 100 адреса и дальше,

Comment: наверное стоит хотя бы базу получить все таки. `all_hosts = all_hosts[99:]`

Comment: спасибо, база есть, но именно работа с сетевыми командами в новинку

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно отобрать адреса, начиная с `*.100`. Может и как-то проще можно, но я библиотеку `ipaddress` не знаю, не нашёл как по простому младшую часть адреса получить:

```
# all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())
all_hosts = [ip for ip in ip_net.hosts() if int(str(ip).split('.')[-1]) >= 100]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает)